# Check if image file is available in curl when save facebook profile image. PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, php-curl, save-image

In my project, when user log in from `Facebook`, the profile picture will be saved. It is working. But if there is no image, then also a `0 Byte` file is saving.

**How can I check the url contains image and save only if the image is available**

**The PHP sample code is given below**

```
function DownloadImage($url, $dest){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen($dest, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($curl);   
    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($fp);    
}

try{ 
    $type='large';  
    $social_id='1234';
    DownloadImage('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$social_id.'/picture?type='.$type.'&access_token=[your access token]', $type.'.jpg');


}
catch(Exception $errr){
    echo $errr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always check curl returned header info with `curl_getinfo()` (more at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php))

So in your case you can `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)` to see how much bytes are returned.

Also i think facebook should return different HTTP code if no image found, so you can try `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`. It should be `200` if image found and `404` if not.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it is showing some strings in the page like `0����JFIF���Photoshop 3.08BIM�g1SQQYlr`. Why it is so?

Comment: @Arun: That is the start of the binary data of a JPEG image. So you must be outputting the received data somewhere.